# I would like to create columns that provide count of one variable per another

Tags: r, count, dataset, plyr

I have a data set that looks something like this:

```
id score
a 1
a 5
a 5
b 8
b 3
b 2 
b 9
b 3
b 5
c 3
c 1
d 8
d 3
d 9
```

I'm looking to reshape the data so that I get a count of each number per variable, something like this:

```
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
a 1 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0
b 0 1 2 0 1 0 0 0 1
c 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
d 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1
```

I know that ddply can do this using the count(score==1), count(score ==2) function etc., but my actual data set has values from 1-100 and its inefficient to hardcore in 100 different functions for ddply.

Does anyone have a simple way to do this?

Comment: Just do `table(data)` after converting the score to `factor` i.e. `table(transform(data, score = factor(score, levels =1:9)))`

Comment: Another option is `reshape2::dcast(data, id ~ score, length, value.var = "score")` . You need to add the missing score factors as suggested above.